# What will be the big-O of following code?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

The code:

```
int temp = 0;
for (int h = 1; h <= n; h = h * 2)
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   {
      for (int j = 1; j<=n; j++)
      {
         for (int k = 1; k<i; k++)
         {
            temp++
         }
      }
   }
}
```

According to my calculations, big-O is **lg n * n^4**.
Kindly guide.

Edit: Thank you all for the replies. I understood where I was making the mistake. I really appreciate everyone who participated.

Comment: did you mean `k<i` rather than `i<i`. If so, for me it is lg n*n^3 not n^4

Comment: Seems like you have the right answer already;

I believe h * 2 makes the first loop have O(log n), and all others have n, which means you get log n * n^4.

Since this is big-Oh notation, you should also simlify the expression as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out "i<i". Can you explain? Shouldn't it be n^4 because of the last loop? I mean it'll be summation of i. That is n(n + 1)/2. So, lgn for first loop then lg n * n^2 for next two loops then last loop will be summation which will be replaced by n(n + 1)/2. So, this all be lg n * n^2 * n(n+1)/2. @knightrider

Comment: Thank you for your time, @Stian.

Comment: @Stian - why n^4? There are three inner loops

Comment: @libik It's because of the last loop is running n(n + 1)/2 times, I think.

Comment: @FarazMazhar - no, the last loop together with second loop is running `n(n+1)/2`, then you have third loop running `O(n)`, which is `n^2*(n+1)/2`, which is basically `n^3`

Comment: @libik I see where I was making the mistake. Thanks for clearing it. I was confusing n (n + 1)/2 for only one loop.

Comment: @libik, Seems like I just went about the math the wrong way, I was thinking  4 loops of n, but the first one reduced to ln n. But as cleared up in the answer, I agree it's ln(n) * n^3, and not ln n^4 as I stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (int h = 1; h <= n; h = h * 2) // increment is pow(2). hence executed ln(n) times
{
   for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) // increment is one. Executed n times
   {
      for (int j = 1; j<=n; j++)// increment is one. Executed n times
      {
         // increment is one. Executed i times. See below
         for (int k = 1; k<i; k++)
         {
            temp++
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The `k` loop is executed `i` times. The maximum value of `i` is n. so you can consider it as being executed `n` times always (over approximation)

complexity = ln(n) * n * n * n = ln*pow(n,3)

Another way to look at it... lets exchange i loop and j loop

```
for (int h = 1; h <= n; h = h * 2) // increment is pow(2). hence executed ln(n) times
    {
       for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) // increment is one. Executed n times
       {
          // see below
          for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++)
          {
             for (int k = 1; k<i; k++)
             {
                temp++
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

now look at it.... the total number of executions of (i,k) is `n*(n+1)/2`. so now what is the complexity?

h * j * (i,k) = ln(n) * n * (n*(n+1)/2) == ln(n) * pow(n,3)

Comment: But last loop isn't running till max value of i everytime. It's running for 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + ... + n. Which can be replaced by summation i.e. n(n + 1)/2

Comment: @FarazMazhar the easiest way to think about it is as I explained. Look at the maximum value of k. it is n. It can go never beyond n. That's why it is correct. I will explain what is wrong with using n(n+1)/2 in answer

Comment: Yes, but the first `n` in `n(n + 1)/2` is the `n` times that the `j` loop runs.

Comment: So, we are ignoring (n + 1)/2 part?

Comment: @johnhascall the first `n` n tiles `i` runs not `j`. I was thinking how to explain in a simple manner. You did an awesome job :)

Comment: @FarazMazhar O((n+1)/2) == O(n)

Comment: @FarazMazhar one more way to think about it is... n(n+1)/2 is the *total* number of executions of k loop for all i's. If you are familiar with loop interchange I can give you another way to look at it. But if it is already clear, please accept the answer

Comment: The way you explained i.e. "O((n+1)/2) == O(n)". Summation i to n is n (n + 1) / 2 and O((n + 1) / 2) == O(n) then n ( n + 1) / 2 == (n^2 + n) / 2. Hence, O(n (n+1)/2) == O(n^2).

Comment: @JohnHascall Thanks for your answer, sir. I am just trying to understand so I won't get confused in the future.

Comment: Lets assume that the outermost loop is `log(n)` and the 3rd loop is `n`.  Now lets consider just the 2nd and 4th loops.  It should be clear that when `i` is 1, the inner loop runs 0 times, when it is 2, it runs once.  Adding all these up is 0+1+2+...+n-2, which as you point out is (about) `n(n-1)/2` -- BUT this is value counts BOTH loops.  so the complete total is: log(n) + n + `n*n` (we can ignore the -1 and the /2)

Answer (score 2):

Just for kicks, I ran this code with various values of n:

```
               n                  temp               O?
     -----------        --------------        ---------
               1                     0
              10                  1800        1.8 x n^3
             100               3465000        3.5 x n^3
            1000            4995000000        5.0 x n^3
           10000         6999300000000        7.0 x n^3  (and took a LONG time!)
```

conclusion: log(n) * n^3

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I understood my mistake.

Comment: @JohnHascell Thanks for your addition of the final `n=1E4` iteration to my post!

Answer (score 1):

Knightrider is basically right, but if you want correct numbers, you cant just say "I take the biggest value of `i`".

Yes, it is correct in terms `f(n) = O(...)`, but you can also write `f(n) = O(n^15)` and this will be correct too.

The last loop is executed n-times, then n-1 times, then n-2 times etc., which is `n+n-1+n-2+n-3....+3+2+1` which is `n(n+1)/2`. Now you can multiply it and get `n(n+1)/2 = n^2/2 + n/2`, constants can be ignored in asymptotic operations, which means `n^2/2 + n/2 = Theta(n^2+n)`, which can be also transformed to `n^2+n = Theta(n^2)`

So after all, the result is not changed, BUT you have to be sure.

The final result is `n^3*log_2(n)` as described by knightrider

Comment: Thank you for your reply, sir.

Comment: Just a note regarding the notation of the membership/inclusion of some arbitrary function `f` in some arbitrary set of functions `O(...)`: it isn't fully correct to state that `f(n) = O(...)`, since `O(...)` is the _set_ of all functions that satisfy the Big-O conditions for `...` (generally, there exists infinitely many such func:s for each such cond:s). Hence, we don't say that `f(n)` equals `O(...)`, but rather that `f` _is in_ `O(...)`, i.e., `f ∈ O(...)`. Naturally, any func. `f` that's a member of, say, `O(n^2)`, is a member also of `O(n^3)`, much as you point out in your answer above.

Answer (score 1):

### Analysing the algorithm's complexity using Sigma notation

For the sake of completeness: when analyzing the time complexity of nested and co-dependent loops such as in your algorithm, Sigma notation can be a good tool

[image]

where ⌊x⌋ and ⌈x⌉ are the [floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions).

From the above, it's apparent that an upper bound on the asymptotic behaviour of the algorithm is `O(n^3 log_2(n))`.

---

**Using Sigma notation to estimate the actual number of iterations**

Sigma notation analysis is, in addition to being a rigorous tool for Big-O(-Ω, -Θ) analysis, also useful if we're interested in counting or estimating *the actual number of iterations* of our algorithm.

We compare the estimated number of iterations—using the formula prior to the ≤ symbol above—with the actual number of iterations as presented in @JohnHascell:s answer.

```
// our formula (pseudo-code / matlab-compliant)
numIt(n) = n*ceil(log2(n))*(n^2-n)/2;

// comparison with actual count:
--------------------------------------------------------- 
           n     actual # of iter.   estimated # of iter. 
               (from @JohnHascell)   (from formula above)
------------   -------------------   --------------------
           1                     0                      0
          10                 1 800                  1 800
         100             3 465 000              3 465 000
        1000         4 995 000 000          4 995 000 000
       10000     6 999 300 000 000      6 999 300 000 000
---------------------------------------------------------
```

We see that the count from the formula conforms perfectly with the actual count; in this case, the estimation is in fact an actual count.