# What are the Big O Notation for these for loops?

Tags: java, big-o

I am finishing up an assignment for my class, this particular section involves giving an "analysis" of the running time for several for loops. The instructor specified that he wants a Big Oh Notation answer.

I am building on the foundation that total running time is based on:

```
1)The cost of executing each statement
2)The frequency of execution of each statement
3)The idea of working from "inside and out", specifically starting from inner loops.
```

I know that:

```
total = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < n;i++){
    total++;
}
```

Answer: O(N) its running linear.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n;++i)
     for (int j = 0; j < n;++j)
     total++;
```

Answer: O(N^2), we only care about how large N grows.

I am confused on

```
for (int i = 0;i < n;++i)
     for (j=0;j < n * n;++j)
     ++total;
```

and

```
for ( i = 0;i < n;++i)
     for (j = 0; j < i;++j)
     ++total;
```

And last but not least, I am assuming from my textbook that all Triple nested loops are running at N^3 time?

Comment: The first one runs in O(n^3) and the second one runs in O(n^2)

Comment: These loops are simple enough that you can get it by experimentation. You can try different `n` values (in a loop) and deduce the order. e.g. try n=10 and n=20 and see what the ratio of the `total` is.

Comment: more precisely the last one is `= (n * (n-1)) / 2 = (n^2 - n) / 2 € O(n^2)`

Answer (score 4):

You can analyze your algorithms using Sigma notation, to count/expand the number of iterations run by the inner for loop of your algorithms:

[image]

Where `T_a` covers

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < n * n; ++j)
        ++total;
```

and `T_b`:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    for (j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        ++total;
```

---

Finally, a note on your question:

> "And last but not least, I am assuming from my textbook that all
>   Triple nested loops are running at `N^3` time?"

This is not true: it depends on *how the iterate is increased* as well as *bounded* in the signature of each loop. Compare e.g. with the inner loop in `T_a` above (bounded by `n^2`, but simply increased by `1` in each iteration) or e.g. [the algorithm analyzed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36017644/4573247), or, for a slightly trickier case, [the single loop analyzed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36120126/4573247).

Comment: @SkyZ Happy to help. Sigma notation is really just a helpful tool for estimating the actual number of iterations of some given algorithm, from which the time complexity naturally follows.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the technique, my professor didn't mention anything about sigmas. Where does the divide by 2 come from for T(B)??? Im confused with the second one actually the entire T_b

Comment: @SkyZ The sum rule `\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = n(n+1)/2` is [a standard summation rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation). The remaining sums are simple counts of `1` (or `-1`) over a sum indexing; if you find them difficult to follow, it'll probably easier to grasp them sitting down with paper and pen, trying to follow equality by equality.